# Remove specific directory recursively in linux

Tags: linux

I accidentally deleted my .svn folder in the root directory on the site I'm working on.  So I need to remove all .svn from this project, do a fresh checkout, then overwrite that checkout with what I have.  Problem is, I'm not sure how to recursively delete directories in linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to delete all instances of the .svn directory from a tree, but leave all the other data intact.

```
find <checkout_root> -name .svn -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: You may need to escape the brackets as well, like so: find <checkout_root> -name .svn -type d -exec rm -rf \{\} \;

Comment: The brackets don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

Find makes this task painless.

$ find /path/to/files -name '.svn' -exec rm -rf {} \;

Though you may wish to run one with an echo first to verify the files before you're deleting them.

$ find /path/to/files -name '.svn' -exec echo {} \;

Comment: +1 for being careful first!

Comment: `-exec echo {} \;` can be replaced by `-print` (or nothing at all, since `find` does that by default).

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/files -name .svn -type d -print0 \
    | xargs --null --no-run-if-empty rm --recursive --force --
```